# Any way to interact app when using persistent bottom sheet and viewpager2?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-viewpager2

The problem is that I cannot interact with the app even bottomsheet is collapsed.

Gif image and code as example. Here I cannot click on the two lowest buttons but the highest works. I would like to click also the lower buttons when bottomsheet is collapsed

[image]

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FloatingActionButton fab;
FloatingActionButton fab2;
FloatingActionButton fab3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab2 = findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    fab3 = findViewById(R.id.fab3);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new BottomInfoFragment()).commit();
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICK FAB 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICK FAB 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    fab3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICK FAB 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

BottomInfoFragment

```
public class BottomInfoFragment extends Fragment {

public BottomInfoFragment(){}
View bottomView;
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    bottomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager, container, false);
    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = bottomView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    Padapter adapter = new Padapter(getContext(), Arrays.asList("first view","second view", "third view"));
    viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
    return bottomView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

PageAdapter

```
public final class Padapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final List titleList;

    public Padapter.PageHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.test_layout, parent, false);
        return new Padapter.PageHolder(view);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull Padapter.PageHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.getTextView().setText((CharSequence)this.titleList.get(position));
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder var1, int var2) {
        this.onBindViewHolder((Padapter.PageHolder)var1, var2);
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.titleList.size();
    }

    public Padapter(@NotNull Context context, @NotNull List titleList) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.titleList = titleList;
    }

    public final class PageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @NotNull
        private final TextView textView;

        @NotNull
        public final TextView getTextView() {
            return this.textView;
        }

        public PageHolder(@NotNull View view) {
            super(view);
            this.textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

main_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="344dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="524dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:focusable="true"
        />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

viewpager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

bottom_sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:background="#00FFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```